How to retrieve updated trello card description to highlight difference with the old one?
I'm looking for any solution that doesn't involve using are already mad Trello power-ups to track trello card description updates.
In detail this is what I need:

User A update description of the card
all member receive the notification (maybe through card activities?)
in someway User A should see a diffcheck between the new and old description and check what is added or deleted.

I know I can build a powerup, but maybe you had another idea maybe through butler and payloads? I don't know, I only have javascript so I thought if I could build a diff checker maybe on a sharepoint space and send to this the two version of the texts?
I'm open to different ideas.
